# Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: javascript, node.js

Проект:
https://github.com/tamaspiros/advanced-chat

Сделал все по инструкции но полетело верстка CSS + проблема с файлом `socket.io` в консоли Chrome. Не знаю как решить проблему.
Если смотреть инструкцию я заменял там на свой IP, но ничего не прокатывало!

Также постоянно вылезает вот такая ошибка в терминале:

```
info - socket.io started
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
warn - error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
```

Я уже писал этот вопрос, но мне никто не помог!
Сможет кто-нибудь запустить проект или вообще никто??

Answer (score 1):

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE` означает что порт, на котором вы пытаетесь запустить приложение, уже занят - другим приложением или другим инстансом вашего же чата. 
Пропишите другой порт в конфиге.

По умолчанию там скорее всего или 80, или 3000, пропишите другое значение и на сервере и на клиенте.

Узнать кто именно занял порт можно запустив

```
netstat -aon | find ":80"
```

или

```
netstat -aon | find ":3000"
```

последней колонкой вы выводе будет ID процесса.

Answer (score 0):

Про порт уже написали :3000. Поменять его можно либо в server.js(11 строка), либо установив переменную окружения(см. server.js)

Верстка не слетала, она просто не установилась. Чтобы исправить выполните в консоли

```
bower install
```